# JQuery that can operate a flatbed scanner

Tags: jquery

I want to know if it is possible to use JQuery to operate a normal flatbed scanner. It should simply send the scan command to the scanner and then upload it.

Is something like this possible? 
It would seem that this is not possible. Which framework can be used to achieve this?

Comment: no, it is not possible. that sounds like it could be used to scan unsuspecting users files

Answer (score 0):

No.

jQuery is great at making web pages easier to work with. It's less useful for interacting with flatbed scanners.

Comment: Is there any other framework in which this is possible? The reason being the form requires the user to submit a scanned proof of payment. This is to make it more user friendly, as it scans and then uploads the file

Comment: The user would need to scan the document to a folder then you'd upload the document as a separate step in your web application - lots of jQuery widgets to upload files.